# Uploading packages to Gemfury using RubyGems CLI silently failing

Tags: rubygems, gem-fury

I am trying to upload a package to Gemfury using RubyGems as described [here](https://gemfury.com/help/install-gems#uploading-packages-using-rubygems-cli). The command below is failing without error messages:

```sh
$ gem push fizzbuzz-0.1.8.gem --key fury_push_token --host https://push.fury.io/dlresende/
Pushing gem to https://push.fury.io/dlresende/...

$ echo $?
1
```

Enabling `debug` and `backtrace` reveals an error which doesn't seem related with the upload per se:

```sh
$ gem push fizzbuzz-0.1.8.gem --key fury_push_token --host https://push.fury.io/dlresende/ --debug --backtrace
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/dlresende/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/dlresende/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443
Pushing gem to https://push.fury.io/dlresende/...

$ echo $?
1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was an URL problem...

Enabling `verbose` revealed an extra `/` in the URL, which seemed to be causing the issue:

```sh
$ gem push fizzbuzz-0.1.8.gem --key fury_push_token --host https://push.fury.io/dlresende/ --debug --backtrace --verbose
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/dlresende/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/dlresende/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Pushing gem to https://push.fury.io/dlresende/...
POST https://push.fury.io/dlresende//api/v1/gems
301 Moved Permanently

$ echo $?
1
```

Using `https://push.fury.io/dlresende` instead of `https://push.fury.io/dlresende/` (without the `/` in the end, as opposed to what is described in the [docs](https://gemfury.com/help/install-gems#uploading-packages-using-rubygems-cli)) fixed the issue:

```sh
$ gem push fizzbuzz-0.1.8.gem --key fury_push_token --host https://push.fury.io/dlresende --debug --backtrace --verbose
NOTE:  Debugging mode prints all exceptions even when rescued
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /Users/dlresende/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/fileutils.rb:250 - File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - /Users/dlresende/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%443
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
Pushing gem to https://push.fury.io/dlresende...
POST https://push.fury.io/dlresende/api/v1/gems
200 OK
~~> Processing package upload
    Uploading            ... ok
$ echo $?
0
```